# Javascript array of image sequences - return only first image in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, image-processing

I'm working on an Extendscript tool for Adobe After Effects, and I'm trying to figure out one thing. Extendscript is just Javascript with some Adobe fluff added on top, but pretty much anything Javascript that isn't browser-specific works.

I have a script I've been using/developing for some time now which greatly simplifies importing thousands of images in image sequences. Everything is working great but there's one specific area that runs really slowly when you start getting into thousands of images and I'm trying to figure out how to speed it up.

What I am trying to optimize is going through an array of potentially thousands of image files, and concatenating it down to just the first image in the sequence. For example my array might be: [img.001.png, img.002.png, img.003.png, img.004.png, img.005.png] and what I want to do is remove every instance of "img.###.png" except for the first one. So after my function I would have just: [img.001.png].

Here's how I do it right now:
1) I take array item A, regex out the number sequence
2) then array item B, regex out the number sequence
3) and compare the two to see if they are identical. If they are I splice out item B

This works 100% of the time which is awesome, but is quite slow when you get above a thousand or two images... What I'm trying to do is find a way to do this "pruning" step more quickly. A friend of mine told me regex is pretty slow so maybe I need to do it without regex? I also found several native JavaScript array methods that might help such as forEach() every() and filter() but I don't see how these are going to be faster because I still need to do 2 regex evaluations, and I still need to compare the items to each other.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

- Spencer

Here's a snippet of my existing code:

```
currentFolder = new Folder ("//12.34.5.67/my folder on the network/")
var folderChildren = currentFolder.getFiles().sort();

var searcher = new RegExp("\\d{3,5}[.]");
for (var i = 0; i < folderChildren.length; i++) {
    // Go through the array and strip out all elements that are the same once their numbers have been removed with a regex
    if (i > 0) {
        currentResult = searcher.exec(folderChildren[i].name); //check if a sequence
        if (currentResult) { // it is a sequence
            // first parse out the comparison strings - current item and item before
            var testNameBefore = folderChildren[i-1].name;

            //if we have a sequence before our current item, we need to delete the numbers.
            var beforeNum = searcher.exec(testNameBefore);
            if (beforeNum) {
                testNameBefore = testNameBefore.substring(0, testNameBefore.length-8);
            }

            var testNameCurrent = folderChildren[i].name;
            testNameCurrent = folderChildren[i].name.substring(0, testNameCurrent.length-8);

            //compare to the element before it and delete if the same!!
            if (testNameBefore == testNameCurrent) {
                folderChildren.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file format always *.Number.png?

Comment: It always ends in Number.png but not always with a period before the number. And the number sequence is not always 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a code snippet to compare, but this runs in just a few milliseconds.

```js
var files = getFiles(),
    cleanedFiles = getDesequencedArray(files);

console.log(`Parsing ${files.length} files.`);
console.log(`Found ${cleanedFiles.length} unique sequences:`);
console.log(cleanedFiles);

function getDesequencedArray(files) {
  return files.reduce(
    function(memo, file) {
      var sequence = file.match(/(.*)\.?\d{3,5}(.*)/);
      if (sequence) {
        if (!memo.found[sequence[1] + sequence[2]]) {
          memo.found[sequence[1] + sequence[2]] = 1;
          memo.files.push(file);
        }
      } else {
        //Did you want the other files included too?
        //memo.files.push(file);
      }
      return memo;
    }, {
      found: {},
      files: []
    }
  ).files;
}

function getFiles() {
  var files = [
    "img1.001.jpg",
    "img1.002.jpg",

    "img1.001.png",
    "img1.002.png",
    "img1.003.png",
    "img1.004.png",

    "img2.011.jpg",
    "img2.012.jpg",
    "img2.013.jpg",
    "img2.014.jpg",

    "img300001.png",
    "img300002.png",
    "img300003.png",
    "img300004.png",

    "img300002.100.png",
    "img300002.200.png",

    "readme.md",
    "index.html"
  ];


  // Adding a bunch of records
  for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    for (
      let i = 1; 
      i <= 1000; 
      files.push(`img-${x}.` + ("00" + i++).substr(-3) + '.png')
    );
  return files;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try it out shortly! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hey Malk, sorry I haven't actually tried this yet (mid a bunch of stuff...) but I just checked out this reference on the reduce method: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) and I don't think it's going to work. I realize I didn't specify that the array will likely contain _multiple_ image sequences at a time!